# to silence/to quieten

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, difference

> The police had managed to silence the protesters.

> The police had managed to quieten the protesters.

I know that "silence" is no sound at all while "quiet" is almost no sound, but apart from that is there any difference between them in the two sentences?

Answer (score 3):

The two sentences convey different things. In the second sentence

> The police had managed to quieten the protesters.

implies that the police got the protesters to calm down somehow, and lessen the intensity of the protests. Maybe they even got the protesters to literally lower their decibel volume. The sentence implies that the protesters' behavior was changed by the police.

---

In the first sentence

> The police had managed to silence the protesters.

the implication is that the police prevented the protesters' message from being heard by the intended audience. This could be because the protesters were literally prevented from protesting, but it could also be that the police prevented the media from covering the protest. This would *silence* the protesters, in that their message wouldn't be heard, but the protesters actions may not have changed at all.

Comment: I would add that "quieten" is not very common and it would sound more natural (to me) to simply say "Thr police had managed to quiet the protestors."

Comment: I believe there are regional differences here, for example between UK English and US English here. In the UK, "quieten" is completely normal.

Comment: @randomhead I think *quieten* is used as well (James says there might be a regional difference here, which I was unaware of). I'll leave the answer as it is to avoid muddying the waters.